# unable to show the Data into the FilteringSelect DOJO Component using ItemFileReadStore

Tags: json, dojo

I am unable to show the Data into the FilteringSelect DJO Component using ItemFileReadStore .
Please help

```
<html>
<head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
 </script>
<script>

dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
dojo.require("dojox.layout.TableContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect"); 
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");

</script>
<script>

function callMe()
{


}

</script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">

<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="orgStore"  url="http://localhost:8099/Hi/MyServlet"></div>
<div dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="selectaccount" store="orgStore"   name="groupId" id="groupId" label="Select Account:"  >MyCombo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my servlet Program :**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Saiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
          response.setContentType("text/x-json;charset=UTF-8");           
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        List list = new ArrayList();

        for(int i =0 ;i<=10;i++)
        {
            list.add("Test");
        }

         JSONObject json =  new JSONObject();
         response.getWriter().write(json.toString());


    }



}
```

Comment: Your servlet is not producing output in the format ItemFileReadStore expects, please see the manual http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#input-data-format .

Comment: Also, why are you asking the same question so many times? 6557356, 6558980, 6556963 and 6502900 are all pretty much duplicates of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet should output json data in the following format:

```
{
   label : "name",
   items : [
       {name : "Name1"},
       {name : "Name2"}
   ]
}
```

Use the JSON library you used in the servlet to generate this kind of json data.

After that, specify the `searchAttr` attribute of `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` to tell it to filter on this attribute in the store.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="selectaccount" store="orgStore"   name="groupId" id="groupId" searchAttr="name" label="Select Account:"  >MyCombo</div>
```